# Define distribution of a refill schedule?

Tags: statistics

Problem:

A certain industrial process uses some liquid y which is stored in a tank. The factory runs all the time and the goal is a continuous production. The consumption of the liquid is normally distributed as such:

X∼N(μ,σ2)

where μ = 100 tons per hour and σ = 20 tons per hour. X > 0 always.

The tank is there for buffering reasons so that on a daily basis the factory doesn't ran out of liquid.

The tank is refilled with trucks with capacity of 25 tons. Define the refills and/or intervals of refill by using proper distributions. Use these to find out how big the tank should be.

Attempt at solution:

I can calcutate the range of consumption (i.e the minimum and maximum consumption per day). I know that refill should happen before the tanks rans out of liquid. The tank could be a large one but I know it costs a lot to build a massive tank. Of cource the tank can't be too small either. The refilling costs money so that can't happen too often.

I don't need a complete solution but just a hint or two on how to approach this. How I can define proper distributions?

Thank you very much for any help you may give!

EDIT: Typos...

Comment: In 99.4% of the hours, consumption is below 150 tons (six truck loads). If you really believe hourly consumption is exactly normal, then no number (instead of 150) will cover 100% of hours. (But then you can't be sure consumption is never negative.) It seems you need to make some unstated assumptions to be absolutely sure the tank is never empty.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by negative consumption?

Comment: Your Question says "$X > 0$ always. Technically, that's impossible for a normal distribution. However you can have $P(X < 0)$ **very small** (small enough that it's OK to pretend the probability is essentially $0.$ For $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=20)$ its $2.87 \times 10^{-7}.$ In ten years you're not likely to see an hour with $X < 0,$

Answer (score 1):

Conditioning on the event that $\{X>0\}$ complicates the problem, so I will assume the hourly consumption rate is $N(100,20^2)$.

Set $S_t=A_0+25\lfloor nt \rfloor -C_t$ where $C_t\sim N(100t,20^2t)$ is the amount of liquid (in tons) consumed after $t$ hours, $n$ is the number of times the truck arrives (uniformly) each hour,  and $A_0$ is the initial amount of liquid in the tank (in tons). Then $S_t\sim N(A_0 + 25 \lfloor nt \rfloor - 100t,20^2t)$ denotes the amount of liquid in the tank after $t$ hours. The probability of there being some liquid in the tank after $t$ hours equals $$P(S_t>0)=P\Bigg(Z>\frac{100t-A_0-25 \lfloor nt \rfloor}{20 \sqrt{t}}\Bigg)$$ If we require that this probability exceeds some value $p_0$ we would need that $$\frac{100t-A_0-25 \lfloor nt \rfloor}{20 \sqrt{t}}<z_{p_0} \iff A_0+25 \lfloor nt \rfloor >100t-20z_{p_0}\sqrt{t}$$ where $z_{p_0}=\Phi^{-1}(1-p_0)$. Replacing $t=24$ and $p_0=0.99$ unveils an attractive condition that relates the initial amount in the tank, $A_0$, and the number of times per hour the tank gets filled, $n$ so that the tank isn't empty with probability $99$% after $24$ hours: $$A_0+600n >2627.9$$

Comment: Awesome stuff! Makes some much sense.